# Receive slack bot messages via requests to external URL

Tags: google-app-engine, slack-api

**Is it possible to receive direct messages on behalf of a slack bot via POST requests to a certain domain?**

I want to have an endpoint in Google App Engine that receives incoming direct messages from Slack via POST requests, and posts messages back via the API. Is it possible?

Comment: You might want to add more detail to the question (like the language used), but the basics of what you're describing is very simple. Creating an HTTP endpoint in AppEngine and making an HTTP Request from it are both very simple. If that's all you need I can give you an example if you pick a language.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm using Python, and I already created an endpoint in AppEngine. The problem is that in order to receive direct messages in real time, it seems like I have to keep a live socket to Slack and read messages through it... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). Create a bot, subscribe to message.im events, and set your endpoint as the callback URL

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set up an "outgoing webhook"in slack and point it to whatever endpoint you need on your GAE server. In order to respond just use an "incoming webhook" to receive the answer.

Comment: Docs: "The outgoing webhook integration is only available in public channels." I want to receive direct messages sent to a specific bot in Slack, not public channels. Possible?